# Synchronising rhythm game notes by changing the maxValue in Mathf.Lerp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLw9E.jpg)

I can't describe the problem thoroughly because I don't know rhythm game terms.

*In the picture*

- The white cube Note represents the object which the player needs to hit on time.
- The green rectangle Line is the representation of the timing. When the Note perfectly lines up with the Line is when the player presses a button to hit the note.

Now the problem is, I cannot seem to find a way to make the Note perfectly line up with the Line using Mathf.Lerp while it still reaches the end.

```cs
void GenerateBeat()
    {

        if (timeItems.Count == 0)
            return;

        if (timeItems.Peek() <= currentBeatPosition + BeatLookForwardValue)
        {
            Debug.Log("Item instantiated, Spawned At : " + currentBeatPosition + " Will reach 0 at : " + timeItems.Peek());
            GameObject obj = Instantiate(tempSpawnObject);
            obj.transform.SetParent(parentObject.transform);
            existingBeats.Add(obj);
            existingBeatsTime.Add(currentBeatPosition);
            timeItems.Dequeue();

        }
            
    }
```

```cs
 void MoveBeat()
    {
       // if (timeItems.Count == 0)
       //     return;

        for (int i = 0; i < existingBeats.Count; i++)
        {
            NoteBeatline beatline = existingBeats[i].GetComponent<NoteBeatline>();
            Vector2 StartingPos = new Vector2(0, 800f);
            Vector2 EndPos = new Vector2(0, 0);
             float offset = (endTime[i] - existingBeatsTime[i]) / 3;
            float time = Mathf.InverseLerp(existingBeatsTime[i], endTime[i] + offset, currentBeatPosition);
            beatline.Image.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector2.Lerp(StartingPos, EndPos, time);
        }
    }
```

[Edit]
Sorry for the lack of clarification.

I'm trying to synchronise Notes by adding extra value to the endTime because existingBeatsTime (keeps track of the time at which the object is spawned) can vary depending on how great BeatLookFOrwardValue is.currentBeatPosition represents how long in beat time has passed since the start of the song, so I cannot manipulate the value.

the endTime value is always a constant, set by me
and items in timeItems are identical to the items in endTime.

the whole background colour of dark cyan is currently 800 units
and the y position of the green horizontal line is 600
so that the Notes can perfectly line up with the green line
when

```cs
 float time = Mathf.InverseLerp(existingBeatsTime[i], endTime[i] + offset, currentBeatPosition);
```

is 0.75f.

I did more research and experiment after I posted this,
and found out

```cs
float offset = (endTime[i] - existingBeatsTime[i]) / 3;
```

somehow synchronises the Notes, but I don't understand how.

Please feel free to comment on my explanation.
This is my first time posting a question on StackOverflow and explaining my coding problem to someone else.

I will try to provide more information if it is still lack.

Answer (score 0):

"Currently, Notes reach the end when currentBeatPosition == endTime.
But I want to make them reach the Line when currentBeatPosition == endTime"

So, they are lerping across the correct distance? They are just doing it a bit too fast yeah? So to fix it you can increase the total time over which they are lerping. So they reach the line at endTime and reach the end a little bit later.

1. get the ratio, distance from start to end / distance from start to line
2. Multiply the total time they are lerping over by this ratio.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me.
I just edited the question for more clarification.

I don't intend to achieve synchronisation by increasing the time which it takes to travel, rather I'm trying to synchronise it by adding extra lerp distance in
`float offset = (endTime[i] - existingBeatsTime[i]) / 3;
float time = Mathf.InverseLerp(existingBeatsTime[i], endTime[i] + offset, currentBeatPosition);
`
It seems like there is a relationship between the offset value and the size of the game panel. The current offset gives me a somewhat synchronised outcome in the current size of the panel.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally fixed the synchronisaton problem.

I found out that there's [Mathf.LerpUnclamped()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.LerpUnclamped.html) which can extrapolate the return value. So I had to change

```cs
beatline.Image.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector2.Lerp(StartingPos, EndPos, time);
```

to

```cs
beatline.Image.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector2.LerpUnclamped(StartingPos, EndPos, time);
```

this. Since it can extrapolate I was able to set the endPos to the position of the green line.

Additionally, I also had to make my own [Mathf.InverseLerp()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.InverseLerp.html) which will be the unclamped version of [Mathf.InverseLerp()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.InverseLerp.html).

```cs
public static float InverseLerpUnclamped(float startValue, float maxValue, float inbetweenValue)
    {
        return (inbetweenValue - startValue) / (maxValue - startValue);
    }
```

Finally, I could simply get it working by these two lines of code.

```cs
float time = Tools.InverseLerpUnclamped(existingBeatsTime[i], endTime[i], currentBeatPosition);
beatline.Image.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector2.LerpUnclamped(StartingPos, EndPos, time);
```